# Elasticsearch percolate query with fuzzy search

Tags: elasticsearch, fuzzy-search, elasticsearch-5, elasticsearch-percolate

I recently came across [percolate query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-percolate-query.html#_example_3) and I am wondering whether it can be used along with fuzzy search options? I am following the example given in the link and noticed that if there is a typo, it doesn't match, so I am wondering if there is a way to fix this using fuzzy search.

```
GET /my-index/_search
{
    "query" : {
        "percolate" : {
            "field": "query",
            "document_type" : "doctype",
            "document" : {
                "message" : "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog"
            }
        }
    },
    "highlight": {
      "fields": {
        "message": {}
      }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you been able to solve the issue? I would like to know the same.